# Object oriented Tkinter

Tags: python, oop, tkinter, tkinter-button

I am trying to write a gui which as a class which is the main application. A single instance of that class is created in the main root. At the same time I want a submit button to be clicked where some values are verified before a further submission to write the data. I am trying to do this by creating a new class for the Toplevel pop up window. But I am not sure how best to structure this. Ideally an instance of the pop up window class would be created each time the button is selected. It seems like with the way I have structured it another instance of the main application class has been created. I am a little confused how to correctly do this using OOP.

Below is some sample code to illustrate the problem.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class Window(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.title = "TITLE"
        self.master = master
        self.submit = ttk.Button(self, text = 'SUBMIT', command = self.click_submit_button)
        self.submit.grid(row = 0, column = 2, padx = 20, pady = 20)

    def click_submit_button(self):
        self.submit_pop_up = submit_button(self.master)
        print('New PopUp')

class submit_button(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Toplevel.__init__(self, master)
        self.master = master
        self.title = 'TITLE'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = Window(root)
    app.pack()
    root.mainloop()
```

There is something missing from my understanding of the best approach to using OOP to structure a program like this.

Comment: MY unsolicited advice, if you are interested in learning OOP GUI programming, is to throw out the hopelessly antiquated and band-aided Tkinter and move to a REAL GUI framework, like Qt or wxWidgets.  tkinter is a 30-year-old legacy product and has not aged well.

Comment: It is not clear what your problem is.

Comment: @TimRoberts: tkinter may look outdated, but I think it's a perfect toolkit to learn the fundamentals of event-driven GUI programming. There are plenty of real world uses for a toolkit like Tkinter.

Comment: The ONLY reason that is even remotely true is that it ships in the box.  Every API results in the construction of a command line that gets sent to an interpreter for an entirely different language.  I was hoping that once real GUI libraries became widely available, Python would remove tkinter.  Alas.

Comment: I am also not sure what exactly you are having trouble with?  I also think tkinter is a great tool for learning.

Comment: @TimRoberts You can sell Tkinter without any conditions and besides that, if you really want something special in your GUI Toolkit you have to do it yourself anyway. Other Toolkits may suits for a better looking "lazy standard". I don't see how this makes them superior.

Comment: @Thingamabobs: _"The ONLY reason that is even remotely true is that it ships in the box. Every API results in the construction of a command line that gets sent to an interpreter for an entirely different language."_ - why do you think that matters? It gets the job done and it's easy to use.

Comment: My problem here is that I am trying to create an instance of a new class, the issue I am having is that the pop-up window from Toplevel seems to be an instance of the application class. There's something I haven't done with OOP which is making this so.

Comment: Why do you think that the pop-up window is an instance of the application class?

Comment: There is no way to change the title of the Toplevel window. But I guess this is irrelevant. One question I do have is that the class has been inherited from tk.Toplevel, I am wondering about how to best organize this Toplevel to place widgets on it. Can I create a Frame on the toplevel to then place the widgets?

Comment: You need to use `self.title('...')` instead of `self.title = ...`.  And you can create any tkinter widgets inside a `Toplevel` instance.

Comment: @acw1668. It should be like this....self.master = master
      self.master.title( "TITLE")

Comment: @Tim Williams. Pay attention acw1668, self.master = master should place before title.

Comment: Use self.master for all widget only.

Comment: " Ideally an instance of the pop up window class would be created each time the button is selected." I think the code already does this, and I don't understand why you believe otherwise. If there is an identifiable *problem with* the observed behaviour of the code, then that is a [debugging](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) question, not an OO design question.

Answer (score 0):

## Solution

Just make the `submit_button` class inherit the `Window` class and instantiate only the `submiit_button` class. With this, you don't need to instantiate the `Window` class. This allows for a special trick so that you can access the attributes of the `submit_class` class in the `Window` class without creating an instance. Just use `self` since it is actually an instance of the `submit_class` passed on to the `Window` class. Here is your code with that. There are many other suggestions and to know, see the code.

## Suggestions

In the first place, why are you making `submit_button` a separate class? You could include it as a method of `Window` class. If you have good reason, it is ok but otherwise make it a method.
And also, why are you creating a root window and making the window class save it as an attribute? Just make the `Window` class inherit `tk.Tk` instead of `tk.Frame`. You can then create frame inside the `__init__` function. Here is the code working code with these rectifications:

## Code

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class Window(tk.Tk):

  def __init__(self):
      super().__init__()

      self.title("TITLE")

      self.submit = ttk.Button(self, text = 'SUBMIT', command = self.click_submit_button)
      self.submit.grid(row = 0, column = 2, padx = 20, pady = 20)

class submit_button(Window):

  def __init__(self):
      super().__init__()
      self.submit_pop_up = tk.Toplevel(self)
      self.submit_pop_up.withdraw()
      print(self.submit_pop_up)

  def click_submit_button(self):
      self.submit_pop_up.deiconify()
      print('New PopUp')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = submit_button()
    app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Is that what you want? You should used `self.master` for all widgets.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


class Window(tk.Frame):

  def __init__(self, master=None):    
      tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
            
      self.master = master
      self.master.title( "TITLE")
    
      self.submit = ttk.Button(self.master, text='SUBMIT', command=self.click_submit_button)
      self.submit.grid(row=0, column=2, padx=20, pady=20)
    
  def click_submit_button(self):
    
      self.submit_pop_up = submit_button(self.master)
    
      print('New PopUp')

class submit_button(tk.Toplevel):

    def __init__(self, master):

        tk.Toplevel.__init__(self, master)

        self.master = master

        self.master.title('TITLE')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = Window(root)
    #app.pack()
    root.mainloop()
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class GroceryStore:
def **init**(self, master):
self.master = master
self.master.title('Grocery Store')
self.create_widgets()

```
def create_widgets(self):
    # Create main frame
    self.main_frame = ttk.Frame(self.master, padding='10')
    self.main_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=(tk.W, tk.E, tk.N, tk.S))

    # Create widgets
    self.item_label = ttk.Label(self.main_frame, text='Item:')
    self.item_label.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=tk.W)

    self.item_entry = ttk.Entry(self.main_frame, width=30)
    self.item_entry.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=(tk.W, tk.E))

    self.quantity_label = ttk.Label(self.main_frame, text='Quantity:')
    self.quantity_label.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=tk.W)

    self.quantity_entry = ttk.Entry(self.main_frame, width=30)
    self.quantity_entry.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=(tk.W, tk.E))

    self.price_label = ttk.Label(self.main_frame, text='Price (PHP):')
    self.price_label.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=tk.W)

    self.price_entry = ttk.Entry(self.main_frame, width=30)
    self.price_entry.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky=(tk.W, tk.E))

    self.add_button = ttk.Button(self.main_frame, text='Add to Cart', command=self.add_to_cart)
    self.add_button.grid(row=3, column=0, columnspan=2)

    self.cart_label = ttk.Label(self.main_frame, text='Cart:')
    self.cart_label.grid(row=4, column=0, sticky=tk.W)

    self.cart_listbox = tk.Listbox(self.main_frame, width=50, height=15)
    self.cart_listbox.grid(row=5, column=0, columnspan=2)

    self.remove_button = ttk.Button(self.main_frame, text='Remove from Cart', command=self.remove_from_cart)
    self.remove_button.grid(row=6, column=0, columnspan=2)

    self.remove_button = ttk.Button(self.main_frame, text='Remove All', command=self.remove_from_cart)
    self.remove_button.grid(row=12, column=0, columnspan=8)

def add_to_cart(self):
    item = self.item_entry.get()
    quantity = self.quantity_entry.get()
    price = self.price_entry.get()
    if item and quantity and price:
        self.cart_listbox.insert(tk.END, f'{item} - {quantity} units - ${price}')
        self.item_entry.delete(0, tk.END)
        self.quantity_entry.delete(0, tk.END)
        self.price_entry.delete(0, tk.END)

def remove_from_cart(self):
    selected_item = self.cart_listbox.curselection()
    if selected_item:
        self.cart_listbox.delete(selected_item[0])

def remove_All_from_cart(self):
    selected_item = self.cart_listbox.curselection()
    if selected_item:
        self.cart_listbox.delete(selected_item[5])
```

def main():
root = tk.Tk()
GroceryStore(root)
root.mainloop()

if **name** == '**main**':
main()